# Cadastrar no Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

Boa Tarde pessoal.
Estou tendo dificuldades pra implementar o meu Cadastrar no **Spring Boot**. Estou querendo fazer o método com três formas(`if,else if,else`) que se estiver tudo certo ele cadastra, que se já existir alguém com aquele email então da "Existente" e o erro qualquer é "Inválido". Porém não esta funcionando, o método que eu fiz pra ver se já existe no banco a Pessoa que estou cadastrando esta correto? Alguém pode me ajudar como eu coloco mensagem e se o código esta certo ou se tem algum jeito de melhorar. Obrigado.

---

`Repository`.

```
String findByEmail(String email)

------
Controller.

@PostMapping  
public ResponseEntity<Pessoa> cadastrar(@RequestBody Pessoa p) {  
        if(p.getEmail() == repository.findByEmail(p.getEmail())){    
            return ResponseEntity.status(400).build();  
        }else if(p != null) {  
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(repository.save(p));
        }else {  
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();  
        }    
    }
```

Comment: quando você diz que não está funcionando precisa ser mais claro, o que não está funcionando ? a validação ? algum erro tá sendo cuspido ? qual o comportamento da requisição ?

Comment: Pelo que vejo você não chamou nada para cadastrar

Comment: @IsaíasdeLimaCoelho quando eu cadastro um email com um que já existe no banco de dados da tabela Pessoa ele adiciona do mesmo jeito e eu não quero isso, e eu queria saber como adiciona alguma mensagem tipo "Cadastrado com sucesso" " Existente" " Inválido "

Comment: @nullptr arrumei !

Comment: @IsaíasdeLimaCoelho estou usando o Postman pra fazer as requisições, queria que no Response viesse essa mensagem sabe? E você tem alguma dica de melhorar esse código? estou achando muito porco.

Answer (score 1):

Oi,

Eu não colocaria essa lógica de existente ou novo cadastro no mesmo serviço (rest) eu acho que o controller deveria ter um método para cadastrar novo (POST) e um método para atualizar um existente (PUT), até mesmo para aproveitar a semantica (significado dos métodos HTTP, PUT = atualizar, POST = inserir, DELETE = remover, etc)

Ficaria algo assim

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> cadastrar(@RequestBody Pessoa p) {
    try {
        Pessoa novaPessoa = service.save(p);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/pessoas/" + novaPessoa.getId())).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar uma essoa", e);
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<?> atualizar(@RequestBody Pessoa p, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    try {
        p.setId(id);
        service.save(p);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus..BAD_REQUEST,
                "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar atualizar os dados da pessoa de id " + id, e);
    }
}
```

E para testar a sua API

```
POST /pessoas - adiciona uma pessoa
PUT /pessoas/{1} - atualiza os dados da pessoa de id 1
```

Comment: Se você setar o id o repositório já vai saber que você está atualizando os dados de uma entidade já existente

Comment: No meu exemplo eu passei o id para atualizar, mas voce pode passar outra coisa como o email, e na hora de buscar o id voce usa o email

Comment: Uoooooou, obrigado André !! Eu já vi muitas pessoas utilizando ResponseEntity<?> mas nunca consegui entender o porque disso, poderia me resumir? 
Sobre o .noContent o que é?

Comment: O ResponseEntity é uma classe do spring web que basicamente "encapsula" uma resposta    e passa um status de retorno (que deve seguir as convensões dos métodos http), o noContent por exemplo retorna um status 204

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP#204_Nenhum_conte%C3%BAdo!

204 Nenhum conteúdo
O servidor processou a solicitação com sucesso, mas não é necessário nenhuma resposta.

Comment: Para deixar mais limpo, poderia-se manter o `@PostMapping` e `@PutMapping`